# tweetsharp / SendTweetOptions - Using The Location Parameters

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

I am trying to use the location parameters in TweetSharp's SendTweetOptions object.

The following code works but once tweeted it does not include any location specific data (latitude & longitude do contain valid values)...

```
        SendTweetOptions options = new SendTweetOptions();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(latitude) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(longitude))
        {
            options.DisplayCoordinates = true;
            options.Lat = double.Parse(latitude);
            options.Long = double.Parse(longitude);            
        }

        options.Status = message;

        try
        {
            TwitterStatus s = twitterService.SendTweet(options);
        }
        catch (Exception e) { throw e; }
```

I can't find any reference to the PlaceId attribute on the SendTweetOptions object, is this required? What should it contain (it is a long datatype).

UPDATE:

Undocumented in tweetsharp. I have found a reference to a place_id attribute in twitter's API:

Defined as: A place in the world.

These IDs can be retrieved from GET geo/reverse_geocode.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/geo/reverse_geocode

Version 1.1

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/geo/search

Answer (score 0):

This has been testing me all afternoon! Requests were being processed successfully but not being displayed.

From the twitter API documentation:

> Any geo-tagging parameters in the update will be ignored if geo_enabled for the user is false (this is the default setting for all users unless the user has enabled geolocation in their settings).

Log into twitter and enable "Add a location to my Tweets" which is in the privacy settings.